# tensorflow: incompatible shapes related to batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have an issue training my tensorflow model which is seemingly related to batch size. If I set the batch size to 1 it executes fine.

If I set the batch size to 6 and provide 13 records I receive this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [34,2] vs. [32,2]
```

If I set the batch size to 32 and provide 64 records I receive this error:

```
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [34,2] vs. [32,2]
```

I did this last check to see if they had to be multiples of batch size, but it appears not.

The shape of my model input is (960, 960, 3), and the output shape is (2).

Here is the code for my data generator:

```
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
'Generates data for Keras'

def __init__(self,
             directory,
             collection_name,
             batch_size=32,
             target_size=(128, 128),  # width. height
             shuffle=False,
             limit=None):
    'Initialization'
    self.target_size = target_size
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.directory = directory

    client = MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING)

    # Create the database for our example (we will use the same database throughout the tutorial
    db = client[DB_NAME]
    col = db[collection_name]
    captures = col.find()
    if limit is not None:
        captures = captures.limit(limit)

    self.img_paths = []
    self.img_paths_wo_ext = []

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    self.count = 0

    for capture in captures:
        img_path = os.path.join(directory, capture['ImageName'])
        if os.path.exists(img_path):
            df = df.append({'ImageName': img_path, 'X': capture['X'], 'Y': capture['Y']}, ignore_index=True)
            self.img_paths.append(img_path)
            self.img_paths_wo_ext.append(os.path.splitext(img_path)[0])
        else:
            print(f"{img_path} for capture {capture['_id']} does not exist")
        self.count +=1

    df.set_index('ImageName', inplace=True)

    self.targets = df
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.on_epoch_end()

def __len__(self):
    'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
    return int(np.ceil(len(self.img_paths) / self.batch_size))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    # print(f'index: {index}, batchsize: {self.batch_size}, range:{index*self.batch_size}:{min((index+1)*self.batch_size,len(self.indexes))}, length:{self.indexes}')
    indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:min((index+1)*self.batch_size,len(self.indexes))]

    # Find list of IDs
    list_paths = [self.img_paths[k] for k in indexes]
    list_paths_wo_ext = [self.img_paths_wo_ext[k] for k in indexes]
    # Generate data
    X, y = self.__data_generation(list_paths, list_paths_wo_ext)

    return X, y

def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes after each epoch'
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.img_paths))
    if self.shuffle == True:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

def __data_generation(self, list_paths, list_paths_wo_ext):
    'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    x = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.target_size[1], self.target_size[0], 3))

    # print(list_paths)
    # print(self.targets)

    y = self.targets.loc[list_paths].values

    # Generate data
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_paths):
        size = None
        resize_cache_path = f'{ID}.resized.{self.target_size[0]}x{self.target_size[1]}.png'
        resized = None  # type: Image
        # Store sample
        img = Image.open(ID)  # type: Image
        try:
            img.load()  # required for png.split()
        except BaseException as ex:
            raise Exception(f'Error loading PNG \'{ID}\': {str(ex)}')
        if size is not None:
            raise Exception(f'Image already loaded for ID: {ID}, paths: {list_paths}, size: {size}')
        size = img.size

        if os.path.isfile(resize_cache_path):
            resized = Image.open(resize_cache_path)
            resized.load()
        else:
            resized = img.resize(self.target_size)
            resized.save(resize_cache_path)
        x[i, ] = resized

        y[i][0] = (y[i][0] / size[0]) * self.target_size[0]
        y[i][1] = (y[i][1] / size[1]) * self.target_size[1]

    return x, y
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were two issues.

First was the initialisation of the numpy array, which needed to be capped at the remaining length of the input for the last batch:

```
x = np.empty((min(self.batch_size, len(list_paths)), self.target_size[1], self.target_size[0], 3))
```

Secondly, my input did have duplicates which have since been removed.